# Converting date in milliseconds to date format using JSTL

Tags: java, date, jstl, el

We can convert date in milliseconds to the normal date format using JSTL as follows;

```
    <jsp:useBean id="myDate" class="java.util.Date"/>  
    <c:set target="${myDate}" property="time" value="1365532200000"/>    
    <p>Date: ${myDate}</p>
```

output :

```
    Tue Apr 09 18:30:00 GMT 2013
```

And we can format "myDate" with timeZone="IST" as follows;

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${myDate}"  pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss z" timeZone="IST"/>
```

Consider, If I have milliseconds (1377614766426) value of a date in GMT 5:30 time zone(Tue Aug 27 20:16:06 IST 2013), how can I convert that millisecond value to the date format based on my system time zone?

Answer (score 1):

your date in milliseconds is ALWAYS in UTC. IF you change the amount of milliseconds, it will still be in UTC, but it will just be wrong. For any calculations with Date, use Calendar. If Calendar doesn't suffice, use Joda Time.